# What is the advantage of unroll the loop compared to shorter regex notation with quantified alternatives?

Tags: javascript, regex

Requirement : Two expressions, `exp1` and `exp2`, we need to match one or more of both. So I came up with,

```
(exp1 | exp2)*
```

However in some places, I see the below being used,

```
(exp1 * (exp2 exp1*)*)
```

What is the difference between the two? When would you use one over the other?

Hopefully a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anoopelias/aj9g1w7c/) will make this more clear,

```
var regex1 = /^"([\x00-!#-[\]-\x7f]|\\")*"$/;
var regex2 = /^"([\x00-!#-[\]-\x7f]*(\\"[\x00-!#-[\]-\x7f]*)*)"$/;

var str = '"foo \\"bar\\" baz"';
var r1 = regex1.exec(str);
var r2 = regex2.exec(str);
```

**EDIT:** It looks like there is a difference in behavior between the two apporaches when we capture the groups. The second approach captures the entire string while the first approach captures only the last matching group. See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aj9g1w7c/1/).

Comment: Here's the first one explained - https://regex101.com/r/oQ3pM7/1 ... heres the second one explained - https://regex101.com/r/qZ9wP0/1

Comment: To be clear, there are no spaces apart of these regular expressions correct?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes, that was just for clarity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the two patterns is *potential* efficiency.

The `(exp1 | exp2)*` pattern contains an alternation that automatically disables some internal regex matching optimization. Also, this regex tries to match the pattern at each location in the string.

The `(exp1 * (exp2 exp1*)*)` expression is written acc. to the [**unroll-the-loop**](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) principle:

> This optimisation thechnique is used to optimize repeated alternation of the form `(expr1|expr2|...)*`. These expression are not uncommon, and the use of another repetition inside an alternation may also leads to super-linear match. Super-linear match arise from the underterministic expression `(a*)*`.
>
> The unrolling the loop technique is based on the hypothesis that in most case, you kown in a repeteated alternation, which case should be the most usual and which one is exceptional. We will called the first one, the normal case and the second one, the special case. The general syntax of the unrolling the loop technique could then be written as:
>
> `normal* ( special normal* )*`

So, the `exp1` in your example is *normal* part that is *most common*, and `exp2` is expected to be less frequent. In that case, the efficiency of the unrolled pattern can be really, much higher than that of the other regex since the `normal*` part will grab the whole chunks of input without any need to stop and check *each* location.

Let's see a simple [`"([^"\\]|\\.)*"` regex test against `"some text here"`](https://regex101.com/r/zH1mR0/1): there are 35 steps involved:

[image]

Unrolling it as [`"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"`](https://regex101.com/r/zH1mR0/2) gives a boost to 6 steps as there is much less backtracking.

[image]

**NOTE** that the number of steps at regex101.com does not directly mean one regex is more efficient than another, however, the debug table shows where backtracking occurs, and backtracking *is* resource consuming.

Let's then test the pattern efficiency with JS benchmark.js:

```js
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite();
Benchmark = window.Benchmark;
suite
  .add('Regular RegExp test', function() {
      '"some text here"'.match(/"([^"\\]|\\.)*"/);
    })
  .add('Unrolled RegExp test', function() {
      '"some text here"'.match(/"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"/);
    })
  .on('cycle', function(event) {
    console.log(String(event.target));
  })
  .on('complete', function() {
    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
  })
  .run({ 'async': true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/platform/1.3.1/platform.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/2.1.0/benchmark.js"></script>
```

Results:

```
Regular RegExp test x 9,295,393 ops/sec ±0.69% (64 runs sampled)
Unrolled RegExp test x 12,176,227 ops/sec ±1.17% (64 runs sampled)
Fastest is Unrolled RegExp test
```

Also, since *unroll the loop concept is not language specific*, here is an [online PHP test](https://ideone.com/JaQQlA) (regular pattern yielding *~0.45*, and unrolled one yielding *~0.22* results).

Also see [*Unroll Loop, when to use*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018210/unroll-loop-when-to-use/38018490#38018490).

Comment: I've seen the `"([^"\\]|\\.)*"` example on unroll the loop but I didn't understand it, so I went here.
What is that regex supposed to do originally? Inside the quotes there can be anything but a quote nor a backlash, or a backlash followed by anything? I don't get it

Comment: @Ricola That is correct, inside quotes, there can be any char other than `"` or ``\`` or any escaped char, *zero or more times*. So it matches a substring of any length between two double quotes that may contain any escape sequences.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the difference between the two?

The difference between them is how they exactly match a particular given input. If you think of these as two functions in terms of input and output they are the equivalent, but how the function works to produce the output (match) is different. Both of these regular expressions `(exp1 | exp2)*` and `(exp1 * (exp2 exp1*)*)` will match the exact same input. In other-words you can say they are semantically  equivalent in terms of the given input and a match (output).

> When would you use one over the other?

**Edit**

The second regular expression `(exp1 * (exp2 exp1*)*)` is more optimal due to the loop unrolling technique. See *@Wiktor Stribiżew*'s answer.

---

**Proof**

One way to prove if two regular expressions are equivalent is to see if they have the same DFA. Using [this converter](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa), here are the following DFAs of the regular expressions.

*(Note: `a = exp1` and `b = exp2`)*

```
(a*(ba*)*)
```

[image]

```
(a|b)*
```

[image]

Notice that the first DFA is the same as the second one? The only difference is that the first one isn't minimized. Here is a crud fix to show the minimization of the first DFA:

[image]

Comment: Additionally, the capturing groups capture differently.

Comment: The *neither of these regular expressions are really significantly more optimal than the other to give any significant improvements in performance* is uttetly wrong, you do not take into account the power of the unroll the loop technique in `(exp1 * (exp2 exp1*)*)`. Please revise your answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please elaborate?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala If the capturing groups are different, then that is good enough an answer. I will check that. Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry the answer was more focused on showing the regular expressions are equivalent. I was aware that the second regular expression was more optimal, although I didn't think it was that significant. Anyways I revised my answer.

Comment: Good. Still, I'd call them *semantically equivalent* (what they match), but *functionally different* (how they match).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In terms of CS theory they are equivalent. I tried to mean as in terms of input to output (*blackbox*) they are equivalent. I'll edit and clarify, yeah *semantically* would be more clear.