# Regular expression over EDI File

Tags: regex

I have the following EDI file and need to filter the element LOC+11 but not the LOC+7 and I need all segments between them that the LOC Segment gets repeated but the segments between them not.

At the moment my regex looks like `LOC[^L]*(?:L(?!OC)[^L]*)*` but with that I get 4 results because it filters the loc+7 elemements too.

I only need the 2 results. Could you help me?

```
> NAD+ST+14::92++Test' LOC+11+KOD23277::92' LOC+7+D77::92:Test' LIN+1++
> test AP:IN'IMD+F++12::272:K
> RIPPsadasdRIEM'RFF+ON:EN10514492'RFF+AAN:501'
> DTM+171:20220309:102'RFF+AIF:500'DTM+171:20220305:102'CTA+SC+12414:test,
> test'COM+melweasdsaanigge.frasdasdasdaicke1@test.de:EM'
> COM+?+49-561-490-4173:TE'COM+?+49-561-490-84173:FX' QTY+83:1000:PCE'
> QTY+70:66850:PCE'DTM+51:20080101:102'
> QTY+72:0:PCE'DTM+52:20080101:102'
> QTY+194:1000:PCE'DTM+50:20220224:102'
> RFF+AAU:2143276'DTM+171:20220218:102'
> QTY+194:1000:PCE'DTM+50:20220202:102'
> RFF+AAU:2138944'DTM+171:20220131:102'
> QTY+194:1000:PCE'DTM+50:20220105:102'
> RFF+AAU:2138943'DTM+171:20220103:102' SCC+24'
> QTY+113:1000:PCE'DTM+2:20220412:102'
> QTY+113:1000:PCE'DTM+2:20220503:102'
> QTY+113:1000:PCE'DTM+64:20220530:102'DTM+63:20220605:102'
> QTY+113:1000:PCE'DTM+64:20220620:102'DTM+63:20220626:102'
> QTY+113:1000:PCE'DTM+64:20220711:102'DTM+63:20220717:102'
> QTY+113:1000:PCE'DTM+64:20220801:102'DTM+63:20220807:102' GEI+3+37'
> 
> NAD+ST+14::92++test' LOC+11+KOD823226::92' LOC+7+D86::92:Test' LIN+2++
> test H:IN'IMD+F++12::272:K
> RIPPRIEM'RFF+ON:EN10662318'RFF+AAN:266'DTM+171:20220309:102'
> RFF+AIF:265'DTM+171:20220305:102'CTA+SC+12414:test,
> test'COM+test.test@test.de:EM'
> COM+?+49-561-490-4173:TE'COM+?+49-561-490-84173:FX' QTY+83:200:PCE'
> QTY+70:14319:PCE'DTM+51:20100101:102'
> QTY+72:0:PCE'DTM+52:20100101:102' QTY+194:200:PCE'DTM+50:20220126:102'
> RFF+AAU:2146871'DTM+171:20220121:102'
> QTY+194:200:PCE'DTM+50:20211210:102'RFF+AAU:2146914'DTM+171:20211209:102' QTY+194:200:PCE'DTM+50:20211129:102'RFF+AAU:2139927'DTM+171:20211124:102'SCC+24'
> QTY+113:200:PCE'DTM+2:20220503:102'
> QTY+113:200:PCE'DTM+64:20220606:102'DTM+63:20220612:102'
> QTY+113:200:PCE'DTM+64:20220718:102'DTM+63:20220724:102'
> QTY+113:200:PCE'DTM+64:20220829:102'DTM+63:20220904:102'
> QTY+113:200:PCE'DTM+64:20221010:102'DTM+63:20221016:102'
> 
> UNT+142+1'UNZ+1+2756'
```

Comment: Maybe `LOC\+11[^L]*(?:L(?!OC\+11)[^L]*)*`? See https://regex101.com/r/zn49NI/1

Comment: Or: `LOC\+11.*(?=LOC\+7)`  https://regex101.com/r/xi45fE/1

Comment: What tool or language are you using for doing the searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
LOC\+11[^L]*(?:L(?!OC\+11)[^L]*)*
LOC\+11[\w\W]*?(?=LOC\+11|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zn49NI/1).

*Details*:

- `LOC\+11` - `LOC+11` string
- `[^L]*(?:L(?!OC\+11)[^L]*)*` - any text up to the first occurrence of `LOC+11` substring (uses the [unroll-the-loop principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39142688/3832970)).

Although the results you get with the two patterns above are identical, the first one is much faster provided there are not too many `L`s that are not followed with `+11`.