# Negation Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression to minify the result of the code generated by Laravel's view compiler. The regular expression does nothing more than minify the HTML when compiling a view. I'm having trouble setting the regex to ignore attributes starting with ":" and "@" (eg `... @click="hide(true)" :class="{collapsed: !open}">`), since alpinejs uses them.

In the HTML code:

```html
<select
                                        id="version-switcher"
                                        :class="{test: true}"
                                        aria-label="Localhost version"
                                        class="appearance-none"
                                        @change="window.location = $event.target.value"
                                    >
                                                                                    <option  value="https://localhost">Test</option>
                                                                                    <option selected value="https://localhost">Foo</option>
                                                                            </select>
```

The result should be:

```html
<select id="version-switcher" :class="{test: true}" aria-label="Localhost version" class="appearance-none" @change="window.location = $event.target.value"><option value="https://localhost">Test</option><option selected value="https://localhost">Foo</option></select>
```

However, the output is:

```html
<select id="version-switcher":class="{test: true}" aria-label="Localhost version" class="appearance-none"@change="window.location = $event.target.value"><option value="https://localhost">Test</option><option selected value="https://localhost">Foo</option></select>
```

Note that the attribute starting with : and the one starting with @ are not separate from the previous attribute. The regular expression is: `return preg_replace('/<!--(.*?)-->|\s\B/um', '', $html);`

Can someone help me with this problem please?

Comment: try replacing `\B` with `[\B@:]`

Comment: In this case, [\B@:] cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('~<!--[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*-->|\s+(?=\s[@:]?\w[\w-]*=|[<>])~u', '', $text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ySTPm5/1).

*Details*:

- `<!--[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*-->` - `<!--` string, then zero or more chars other than `-`, then zero or more repetitions of `-` not immediately followed with `->` and then zero or more non-hyphen chars
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=\s[@:]?\w[\w-]*=|[<>])` - that are immediately followed with

  - `\s[@:]?\w[\w-]*=` - a whitespace, an optional `@` or `:`, a word char, zero or more word or `-` chars and then a `=` char
  - `|` - or
  - `[<>]`  - a `<` or `>` char.

Comment: Excellent solution friend Wiktor Stribiżew! He had achieved the same result but differently and with multiple lines (which I don't like).
My solution was: `$pattern = [ '/<!--(.*?)-->|\s\B/', '/<(.*?)>\s+/', '/([@:][a-zA-Z\d-]+=[\"\'][^\"\']*[\"\']\s*)/']; $replacement = [ '', '<$1>', ' $1$2'];`.
Your solution is much simpler. Thank you!

Comment: @MauricioMendoza Note that my regex part matching comments is written with the [unroll-the-loop principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39142688/3832970) so it is probably not that simple, but quite efficient. `\s\B` or `\s(?=\s)` is not correct as it removes spaces inside values, too, not just in between mark-up elements.