# Match only if following string matches pattern

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match an entire string that starts with a certain string and then match any number of characters except `::`, if `::` was matched then only accept if followed by the string `CASE`.

So for example:
A string that starts with `Linus::` followed by 0 or more 1 characters except if `::` then `CASE` has to follow else only matches everything before the `::`.

`Linus::AOPKNS::CASE` would capture the entire string

`Linus::AOPKNS` would capture the entire string

`Linus::AOPKNS::OK` would only capture `Linus::AOPKNS`

I imagine I'd have to use a positive lookahead but I'm not quite sure how to do that considering I wanna match any number of characters before the `::`.

Comment: Just to clarify, the string is allowed to contain a single `:` (or even more than one, as long as they're not consecutive)?

Comment: Also do you want that third example to result in *no match*, or do you want to only capture everything before the `::` (which is the same as the second example)?

Comment: "Just to clarify, the string is allowed to contain a single : (or even more than one, as long as they're not consecutive)?": Yes



"Also do you want that third example to result in no match, or do you want to only capture everything before the :: (which is the same as the second example)?" I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Your first sentence suggests that the string could be `"Linus::A::CASE::B"` or `"Linus::A::B::CASE"` in which case you would want to match `"Linus::A::CASE"` and `"Linus::A"`, respectively. Correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30900794):

```
^                  # Match at the start of the string
Linus::            # 'Linus::', literally,
(?:(?!::).)+       # followed by a sequence of characters that doesn't contain '::'
(?:::CASE)?        # and, optionally, '::CASE'.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZXa7ID/1).

Depending on your use case, you might want to [add a `\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ZXa7ID/2) (word boundary) at the end of the pattern.

Comment: This will still match if there are characters after `CASE` in the string

Comment: @Nick That depends on whether OP wants `CASE` to be the only thing after `::` or not. However, I added a note just in case they do mean the former.

Comment: Agreed, it's not 100% clear, but that was my interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably most easily achieved by matching either a string which includes `::CASE` or if that fails, matching a string up to either `::` or end-of-string:

```
^Linus::(?:.*::CASE$|.*?(?=::|$))
```

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nV05jV/2)

Comment: Hey I know realise my question was not clear. For the third case I wanna capture everything before the ::

Comment: @NOT I've updated my answer to match your requirements

Comment: No problems. Sorry about the slow response, I was in a meeting.

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding you don't want to match over a double colon that's not followed by `CASE` even if there is `::CASE` beyond like in `Linus::AOP::KNS::CASE` but keep  matching any consecutive `::CASE` that might occur like in `Linus::AOPKNS::CASE::CASE`.

```
^Linus::(?:[^:]+|:(?!:)|::CASE)*
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ts0n84/1) (`\n` in the demo is just for multiline showcase)

This will match a string starting with `Linux::` followed by

1. `[^:]+` [One or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [characters that are *not*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a colon
2. `|:(?!:)` [Or](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) a colon [if not followed by](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) another colon
3. `|::CASE` A double colon folllowed by the substring

The `(?:` [non-capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) `)` is repeated any *amount of times*.

---

Or partly [unrolled](https://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) for better performance: [`^Linus::[^:]*(?::(?::CASE|(?!:))[^:]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/S3VfJo/1)

---

Just to mention, all yet provided answers have little differences in what can get matched.

Comment: I would go for the unrolled version, looks more cryptic but it always reminds me when I started learning regex and reading this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39142688/5424988 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786066/5424988

Comment: Oooh, 4th Bird! I felt we'd been much longer around here, than 7 years :) I got right there besides me Jeffrey's Book 3rd edition from 2008 which was my first indepth encounter with deeper regexes understanding. It already has [a nice chapter about Unrolling the Loop](https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/Regular%20Expressions/Mastering%20Regular%20Expressions_%20Understand%20Your%20Data%20and%20Be%20More%20Productive%20%283rd%20ed.%29%20%5BFriedl%202006-08-18%5D.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A696%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22FitH%22%7D%2C807%5D)... (also lots of html parsing examples). 

Answer (score 2):

You can match

```
^Linus::.*?(?=::(?!CASE\b)|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WDYkjL/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^Linus::      # match "Linus::" at the beginning of the string
.*?           # match zero or more characters other than line terminators,
              # as few characters as possible (?)
(?=           # begin a positive lookahead
  ::          # match "::"
  (?!         # begin a negative lookahead
    CASE\b    # match "CASE" followed by a word boundary
  )           # end the negative lookahead
  |           # or
  $           # match the end of the string
)             # end the positive lookahead
```