# Find & replace line breaks between double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, csv, search-regex

I have a CSV file containing some line breaks in values. For example:

```
"Chiffre","Nom","Descriptif court","Tarifs en clair","Période en clair","Adresse 1","CP","Tel","Site","Facebook","Pictos","@Saveurs","@Famille plus","@Img","Accessible en fauteuil roulant en autonomie","Handicapes","Terrasse","Wifi","Chèque Vacances","Titre Restaurant"
6,"Le Chalet d'en Ô","Cuisine traditionnelle (foie gras, magret myrtilles, croustillant chocolat)
Spécialités savoyardes (fondue, tartiflette.. )
Garanti sans burgers.
Tout est fait maison.Cuisine traditionnelle (foie gras, magret myrtilles, croustillant chocolat)
Spécialités savoyardes (fondue, tartiflette.. )
Garanti sans burgers.
Tout est fait maison.","Menu adulte : de 20 à 30 €
Menu enfant : 10 €.

Suggestion du jour le midi en semaine : entrée,plat, dessert : 20€.Menu adulte : de 20 à 30 €
Menu enfant : 10 €.

Suggestion du jour le midi en semaine : entrée,plat, dessert : 20€.","Midi et soir du jeudi au samedi + midi le dimanche et jours fériés.
Juillet et août, midi et soir du mardi au samedi et midi uniquement dimanche et jours fériés.Midi et soir du jeudi au samedi + midi le dimanche et jours fériés.
Juillet et août, midi et soir du mardi au samedi et midi uniquement dimanche et jours fériés.","Le Cropt - Route de Serraval","74230 Les Clefs","+33 4 50 02 09 00","www.lechaletdeno.com",,"A R J X x",,,,,"A","R","J","X","x"
7,"La Cabane - Pisciculture de Montremont","Bar - restaurant au bord de la rivière dans un cadre champêtre avec sa spécialité la truite.","Menu adulte : de 26 à 35 €.","Juin et septembre : du mercredi au dimanche.
Juillet et août : tous les jours à midi + mercredi à samedi le soir.Juin et septembre : du mercredi au dimanche.
Juillet et août : tous les jours à midi + mercredi à samedi le soir.","Pisciculture de Montremont - 100 impasse des Pesetz","74230 Thônes","+33 4 50 02 00 85","pisciculture-montremont.fr",,"A R  X x",,,,,"A","R",,"X","x"
```

Just need to replace any line break with a space (or anything).

Tried a lot of existing solutions, but using `\\n` as search term doesn't seem to work, among other issues.

Any idea? Thanks.

Sublime Text would suffice but if another tool is easier, no problem.

**Edit**: `\n` works fine if I have only this as the search term. But I need to find them only between `"`. The best I got so far is matching all text between `"` with: `(?<=")[^"]*`.

Comment: `\n` works fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure `\n` was used and not `\r` or something? Try `[\r\n]`

Comment: Maybe the obvious, but did you check the regular expression option at replace? It works when I use `\n`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. See edit. `\n` works fine if alone. The regex option is checked. No luck with `\r\n` neither.

Comment: You can try `(?<=")\n(?=")` for a single newline or `(?<=")\n\n(?=")` for two newlines.

Comment: No match... Did it work on your side?

Comment: If you add a tag for a language you can use for the task, I will post one of the solutions above. Or maybe another one if your can do it with another language.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew switched to Javascript as it's the one I know best, but please include other languages as well in your answer :) The best would be a command line that read and search/replace in a file.

Comment: @NicoPrat Please check my answer below. I cleaned my comments here, too.

Comment: Thanks again, that's a pretty solid answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot do that with a text editor in a safe way because the starting and ending delimiters are identical, and any lookaround-based solution, or a `\G` based solution won't work well.

Use some programming language that supports a callback method/function as the replacement argument in a regex replace method/function, match any double quoted substring with

```
"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/66W5QG/1). A simplified version if you do not need to care about literal double quotes is `"[^"]+"`.

**Details**

- `"` - a double quote
- `[^"]*` - 0+ chars other than double quotes
- `(?:` - a grouping construct that is repeated 0+ times

  - `""` - 2 double quotes
  - `[^"]*` - 0+ chars other than double quotes
- `)*` -
- `"` - a double quote.

This regex can be used as follows: read in a file and use the following solutions:

- [python](/questions/tagged/python): `re.sub(r'"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"', lambda m: m.group(0).replace("\n", ""), s)`
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript): `s = s.replace(/"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"/g, function(m) { return m.replace(/\n/g, ''); })`
- [php](/questions/tagged/php): `$s = preg_replace_callback('~"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"~', function($m) { return str_replace("\n", "", $m[0]); }, $s)`
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23): `s = Regex.Replace(s, "\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"", m => m.Value.Replace("\n", ""))`

If you have `\r` and `\n` to remove, as a second step, you may use `.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '')` in JS, `preg_replace('~\R+~', '', $m[0])` in PHP, `m.Value.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n","")` in C# and `m.group(0).replace("\n", "").replace("\n", "")` in Python.

In C#, the full solution will look like

```
using System.IO;
...
var file = "path_to_file";
var path_to_save = "path_to_save";
var contents = string.Empty;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(file, true)) // true for a Unicode encoding
{
    contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
contents = Regex.Replace(contents, "\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"", 
    m => m.Value.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""));
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path_to_save, false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    sw.Write(contents);
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: good solution. It loads whole file as a string object. what is the performance if the file is big?

Comment: @CSK The regex follows the [unroll-the-loop principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018490/3832970) so it is as fast as an NFA regex can be.

Comment: I have no doubt about the regex performance. If the file is 1GB or 10GB. then the String object "contents" will be 1GB or 10GB. not sure how C# handles in this case.

Comment: and the file can't be read by line because '\n' could be existing in double quote.

Comment: @CSK I see, I had a workaround at my former work for that. I wrote a C# app that read the file in chunks of some X megabytes and made replacements there, then the chunks were concatenated and the file was split into chunks of another size and ran a replace the second time.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : great answer thanks! We are trying to use it but would vastly appreciate a little more help with it. Would mean a lot to us if you could have a look at it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73448343/regex-expression-to-replace-newlines-between-quotation-marks-but-only-if-there

Answer (score 3):

Use Notepad++ regex Find-and-Replace:

Find what:

```
(,"[^"]*?)[\r\n]+
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

(There is a single space after $1)

Repeatedly click "Replace All" until no more matches are found.

Comment: this worked very well for me. (btw Notepad++ regex Find-and-Replace is awesome)!

Comment: This also worked for me in Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone arriving here searching for a system shell ([bash](/questions/tagged/bash), etc) answer. You can use the `sed` answer from Alister, from this [unix.com](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/136568-removal-new-line-character-double-quotes.html#postcount302422508) link, or perl.

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -n 'H;g;/^[^"]*"[^"]*\("[^"]*"[^"]*\)*$/d; s/^\n//; y/\n/ /; p; s/.*//; h' current.csv > new.csv
```

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -0777 -pe '                                                                                  
  s{".*?"}{
    ($r = $&) =~ s/\n/ /g;
    $r
  }gsem' < current.csv > new.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -n 'H;g;/^[^"]*"[^"]*\("[^"]*"[^"]*\)*$/d; s/^\n//; s/\n//; p; s/.*//; h' current.csv > new.csv`