# How to read csv with fs readfile when line separator is new line char and csv data has new line characters in it?

Tags: node.js, fs

I am reading the csv using CSVData = fs.readFile(File.csv, "utf-8").

Using new line character as separator CSVData.split(/\r\n|\n/) to read each line.

But there are some rows having data with newline char.

for e.g. in below table row3-colB has data with \n

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u0Te.png)

How I can read such rows using fs? Now our code has many lines and replacing fs with any other liabrary will be a big task. If anyone can suggest alternate solution.

Comment: Per the CSV spec, fields containing newlines should be enclosed in double quotes. For example, the following is just two CSV rows: 'one,two,three\naaa,"b\nbb",ccc'
Is this what your data looks like? Can you include the raw data?

Comment: That is right here is the raw data:
'G88,G8888\n
G99, "G9999\nG99991111",G101010,G101010'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution that I can replace \n in double quotes. Thanks for the hint @Mitch Lillie

[Find & replace line breaks between double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797207/find-replace-line-breaks-between-double-quotes)