# Regex to find and replace emoji names within colons

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji

I'm trying to write a regex (for JavaScript's regex engine) that I can use to do a find and replace in text for emoji names within colons. Like in Slack or Discord when you type `:smiley-face:` and it replaces it when you submit the chat. I'm targeting text nodes only so I don't need to worry about other html inside the text.

Is it possible to write a regex that could match all of the following rules? (text highlighted with monospace blocks = regex positive matches)

`:any-non-whitespace:`
`:text1:`sample2:
`:@(1@#$@SD:` `:s:`
`:nospace::inbetween:` because there are 2 colons in the middle
`:nospace:`middle`:nospace:`

I'm starting with something like this but it's incomplete

```
/:(?!:)\S+:/gim
```

I'm trying to think of all the special cases that might possibly occur doing this. Maybe I'm overthinking it.

There's a lot of Twitch emotes involved so I can't use emoji unicode characters. The regex will find matches and replace with  tags

Comment: I am not quite clear about your rules plz come up with some examples for each of your rules

Comment: Your second example shouldn't be allowed as a valid emoji format. That would make this much easier.

Comment: You may try [`:[^:\s]*(?:::[^:\s]*)*:`](https://regex101.com/r/tjHseH/1). Same as [`:(?:[^:\s]|::)*:`](https://regex101.com/r/tjHseH/2), but a bit more efficient.

Comment: @chrisz Actually OP does not need any. Why did you modify the OP requirements?

Comment: Fransisc0, I rolled back the changes done  by chrisz to your original post. Please check my suggestion and let know if either works.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my mistake, believed it was a formatting error.

Comment: Fransisc0,  I added an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using

```
:[^:\s]*(?:::[^:\s]*)*:
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tjHseH/1). It is the same pattern as [`:(?:[^:\s]|::)*:`](https://regex101.com/r/tjHseH/2), but a bit more efficient because the `(?:..|...)*` part is [unrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018210/unroll-loop-when-to-use/38018490#38018490).

**Details**

- `:` - a colon
- `[^:\s]*` - 0+ chars other than `:` and whitespace
- `(?:` - start of a quantified non-capturing group:

  - `::` - double colon
  - `[^:\s]*` - 0+ chars other than `:` and whitespace
- `)*` - end of grouping, repeated 0 or more times (due to the `*` quantifier)
- `:` - a colon.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this regex?

```
(:(?![\n])[()#$@-\w]+:)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/72),,, in which you can additionally insert `unallowed characters` into the character class of the `(?![\n])` and also additonally insert `allowed characters` into the character class `[()#$@-\w]`

Comment: This splits the double colon `::`.

Comment: @ClasG For your reference, leave this link  https://demos.emojione.com/ascii-smileys.html

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was

```
:(::|[^:\n])+:
```

It matches a string, at least one character long, including surrounding colons, that consists of either

- two colons (`::`), or
- a character that isn't a colon, nor a line feed.

But that's basically what Wiktor had as a (slower) alternative (comments). But I'll leave it here anyway since it's working, as opposed to the other submitted answers ;)

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QJxRCH/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this regx

`/(^|\s)+:([^\s\n\r])+:|^:[^\s\n\r]+/g`

Comment: Answering questions is good but your answer would be much better if it explained what the regex does and how it works.