# Regex to find emoji names with colon and skintone

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, emoji, emoji-tones

I'm using [EmojiMart](https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart) for my parser.

I've seen this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745304/regex-to-find-and-replace-emoji-names-within-colons) but it seem to be different from mine.

So I need to return the emoji names or `:code:` for them to be able to decode it.

So example I have this text:

```
:+1::skin-tone-6::man-pouting:Hello world:skin-tone- 
6:lalalalla:person_with_pouting_face: :poop::skin-tone-11: mamamia 
:smile: :skin-tone-6:
```

It should match the whole `:+1::skin-tone-6:`
and not a separate `:+1:`, `:skin-tone-6::` - only if there’s no space between them. (notice the space between `:smile:` and `:skin-tone-6:` )

Conditions:

It should only match the `:code::skintone:` if skintone is 2-6

If I do `str.split(regex)` this is my expected result (array):

```
- :+1::skin-tone-6:
- :man-pouting:
- Hello world
- :skin-tone-6:
- lalalalla
- :person_with_pouting_face: 
- :poop:
- :skin-tone-11: 
-  mamamia 
- :smile: 
- :skin-tone-6:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `String#split()` with the

```
/(:[^\s:]+(?:::skin-tone-[2-6])?:)/
```

regex. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yxTogT/1).

**Details**

- `:` - a colon
- `[^\s:]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and `:`
- `(?:::skin-tone-[2-6])?` - an optional sequence of

  - `::skin-tone-`  - a literal substring
  - `[2-6]` - a digit from `2` to `6`
- `:` - a colon.

JS demo:

```js
var s = ":+1::skin-tone-6::man-pouting:Hello world:skin-tone-6:lalalalla:person_with_pouting_face: :poop::skin-tone-11: mamamia :smile: :skin-tone-6:";
var reg = /(:[^\s:]+(?:::skin-tone-[2-6])?:)/;
console.log(s.split(reg).filter(x => x.trim().length !=0 ));
```

The `.filter(x => x.trim().length !=0 )` removes all blank items from the resulting array. For ES5 and older, use `.filter(function(x) { return x.trim().length != 0; })`.

Comment: Thank you good sir. I wonder if I can do it on `str.replace(regex, callback)` too.


right now I'm doing `str.split(regex).filter(Boolean).map(emoji => myfunction).join('')`

Just to mimic what replace does. But I think replace is much faster.

Comment: @IamL Do you need to replace them with something else? Yes, something like `.replace(reg, function(match) { return myfunction(match); })` will work.

Comment: yes, however replace will only replace the one with `:+1::skin-tone-6:`. It doesn't "match" other `:code:` (without skintone). I guess I have to use split instead?

Comment: @IamL What is the expected result for the input string?

Comment: The goal here is to replace all `:code:` with a corresponding emoji. 
Before I have something like: 
`str.replace(/(:[+\-\d\w]+:)/gm, match => getEmoji(match))`
However my problem is that some `:code:` looks like `:code::skintone:` (which is what this question is for). with my old regex it returns all `:code:` but since I changed it to your answer, it only replaces the `:code::skintone:` ones and not the `:code:` only.  But I guess that is expected?

Comment: @IamL Really, sorry, I don't get it. See http://jsfiddle.net/ew8akcnd/4/. Is it something like that?

Comment: No worries, you've done enough, But Yeah something like that and the `:poop:` should be replaced as `000` instead of only replacing the `:+1::skin-tone-6:`.

Comment: @IamL :) Forgot about the global modifier, [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Larmgpqd/). When you use a regex in a `split()` method, the default behavior is to find all matches to split with. In `.replace`, it should be defined explicitly.

Comment: ^ same, perfect for matching back to back colon represented emojis