# stringr to extract a column of text

Tags: r, regex, stringr, texreg

I have a string that looks like this:

```
t2 <- "============================================
                       Model 1    Model 2   
--------------------------------------------
education               3.66 ***    2.80 ***
                       (0.65)      (0.59)   
income                  1.04 ***    0.85 ***
                       (0.26)      (0.23)   
type: blue collar      -5.91      -27.55 ***
                       (3.94)      (5.41)   
type: white collar     -8.82 **   -24.12 ***
                       (2.79)      (5.35)   
income x blue collar                3.01 ***
                                   (0.58)   
income x white collar               1.91 *  
                                   (0.81)   
prop. female            0.01        0.08 *  
                       (0.03)      (0.03)   
--------------------------------------------
R^2                     0.83        0.87    
Adj. R^2                0.83        0.86    
Num. obs.              98          98       
============================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05"
```

and I'm trying to extract the left hand column so that I get a vector that looks like this:

```
education
income
type: blue collar
type: white collar
income x blue collar
income x white collar
prop. female
```

I'm new to `regex` and `stringr`, and I'm trying to extract the words that follow a linebreak:

```
library(stringr)
covariates <- str_extract_all(t2, "\n\\w+")
covariates
```

which is getting me a bit closer:

```
[1] "\neducation" "\nincome"    "\ntype"      "\ntype"      "\nincome"    "\nincome"    "\nprop"      "\nR"        
 [9] "\nAdj"       "\nNum"
```

but I can't work out how to capture the entire column of text eg, getting the full "type: blue collar", instead of "\ntype".

Comment: So, only Column 1  values in between two `--------------`s?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Yes, exactly, thank you. Sorry I wasn't clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
covariates <- str_extract_all(
        str_match(t2, "(?ms)^-{3,}\n(.*?)\n-{3,}$")[,2], 
        "(?m)^\\S.*?(?=\\h{2})"
)
```

Or, to make it work much faster, use these [unrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018490/3832970) patterns:

```
covariates <- str_extract_all(
        str_match(t2, "(?m)^-{3,}\n(.*(?:\n(?!-{3,}$).*)*)\n-{3,}$")[,2],
        "(?m)^\\S\\H*(?:\\h(?!\\h)\\H*)*"
)
```

With `str_match(t2, "(?ms)^-{3,}\n(.*?)\n-{3,}$")[,2]`, you extract all text between two lines that are made of 3 or more hyphens. Here are that pattern details:

- `(?ms)` - multiline (making `^` match start of a line and `$` match end of line) and singleline/dotall (making `.` match line breaks, too) modes on -
- `^` - start of a line
- `-{3,}` - three or more hyphens
- `\n` - a newline
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars but as few as possible
- `\n` - a newline
- `-{3,}` - three or more hyphens
- `$` - end of line.

The `(?m)^\\S.*?(?=\\h{2})` is used later on that part of the string and matches

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on
- `^` - start of a line
- `\\S` - a non-whitespace char
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\\h{2})` - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be 2 horizontal whitespaces.

Comment: The edit where you explain how each part of the regex works is invaluable for people learning like me. Do you recommend a particular resource for learning regex?

Comment: @JeremyK.`stringr` uses ICU regex library, and there are quite few resources for it. Use [ICU regex docs](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) as primary reference. ICU is close to Java regex, so a lot will look similar.

Comment: @JeremyK. I added a much better alternative without explanation, because these patterns match exactly the same strings as those above, but are faster. If you need to know more details, please read about [unrolling the loop in regex](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop).

Comment: Can I please ask one more question? Why does `str_match(t2, "(?ms)^-{3,}\n(.*?)\n-{3,}$")` return two different matches (meaning that we then need to do `str_match(t2, "(?ms)^-{3,}\n(.*?)\n-{3,}$")[,2]` to get just the relevant one. If we search for `^-{3,}` I would have thought only the [,1] would be returned, as the [,2] doesn't even begin with `---`. Thank you again for your invaluable help. I've been reading up and working through examples on this.

Comment: @JeremyK. `str_match` searches for a single regex match occurrence in the input string. Each match may contain *captured* substrings, those matched with parenthesized regex parts (unlike `str_extract` that drops the captures). As there is one, `(.*?)`, the output contains a matrix with two columns and as we need the second one,  I used `[,2]`. You may replace the `str_match` with 2 `sub` calls: `sub("\n-{3,}(?:\n.*)?$", "", sub("^.*?\n-{3,}\n", "", t2))`