# Whitespace follows by brackets (non lazy) in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy, python-re

I am trying to do the following: from a list of strings extract anything before the first occurrence (there may be more than  one) of a whitespace followed by a round bracket "(".

I have tried the following:

```
re.findall("(.*)\s\(", line))
```

but it gives the wring results for e.g. the following strings:

> Carrollton (University of West Georgia)[2]*Dahlonega (North Georgia College & State University)[2]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggest you to use: `r'(\S+)\s+\(`

Comment: For the following strings, what do you expect, what else it outputted?

Comment: thanks, not sure I understand what 'r' is in your suggestion. If I try this """re.findall("(\S+)\s+\(", line)""" I get the same problem as before

Comment: @Austin, thanks. The actual output is: "CarrolltonGeorgia)[2]*Dahlonega". The expected output is ""Carrolton".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract anything before the first occurrence of a whitespace char followed by a round bracket `(` you may use `re.search` (this method is meant to extract the first match only):

```
re.search(r'^(.*?)\s\(', text, re.S).group(1)
re.search(r'^\S*(?:\s(?!\()\S*)*', text).group()
```

See [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/NGASkr/1) and [regex #2 demos](https://regex101.com/r/NGASkr/2). Note the second one - though longer - is much more efficient since it follows the [*unroll-the-loop* principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018490/3832970).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars as few as possible,
- `\s\(` - a whitespace and `(` char.

Or, better:

- `^\S*` - start of string and then 0+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s(?!\()\S*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `\s(?!\()` - a whitespace char not followed with `(`
  - `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lneLni):

```
import re
strs = ['Isla Vista (University of California, Santa Barbara)[2]','Carrollton (University of West Georgia)[2]','Dahlonega (North Georgia College & State University)[2]']
rx = re.compile(r'^\S*(?:\s(?!\()\S*)*', re.S)
for s in strs:
    m = rx.search(s) 
    if m:
        print('{} => {}'.format(s, m.group()))
    else:
        print("{}: No match!".format(s))
```

Comment: Wiktor, thank you so much, this was very helpful and a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead for this. Try this regex:

```
[a-z A-Z]+(?=[ ]+[\(]+)
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem with that is that I get 'Vista' as the output of 'Isla Vista (University of California, Santa Barbara)[2]'. I am trying instead to get 'Isla Vista'.