# Regex matching between lines

Tags: regex

I have the following text block:

```
## 8.6.0
- **Upload date:** November 19, 2020
- **Release date:** TBC
- **Internal version:** 1171

### Feature
- dsfdsfds
- sdfdsf
- dsfdsf

### Bug fixes
- sdfsaf
- sdfsad
- sdfsdfdsf

### Internal
- sadfsdfsda
- fsdfgsadfasd
- sdfsda

## 8.5.1
- **Upload date:** November 09, 2020
- **Release date:** November 12, 2020
- **Internal version:** 1170
```

I would like to extract just the first entry e.g. all the text from the start of the first character in `## 8.6.0` up to just before the first character of `## 8.5.1`.

I have tried the following expression:

`[#].*[0-9])(.*?)([#].*[0-9])`

But it doesn't return the right result. How would I write this expression?

Comment: You may try `^(##\h*[\d.]+[\s\S]*?)##\h*[\d.]+`

Comment: You didn't really explain all the conditions but try something like `\A\#\#\s*\d[\s\S]+?(?=\#\#\s*\d|\Z)`. Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NNGLNL/1).

Comment: You can use this `(?=#{2}\s*[\d.]+)[^]+(?=#{2}\s*\d\.?)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```php
^##(?!#).*(?:\n(?!##(?!#)).*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IleRL8/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string (if you use it in an environment with the multiline flag enabled by default, try prepending it with `(?-m)` or use `^(?<![\s\S])`)
- `##(?!#)`  - a `##` substring not followed with another `#`
- `.*`  - the rest of the line
- `(?:\n(?!##).*)*`  - zero or more lines not starting with `##` not followed with another `#`.

Comment: This has the advantage that the final newline characters are not included, assuming that is actually desirable.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood the problem correctly, then

`^## (\d+\.?){3}.+?(?=## \d)`

should work. [Here's a demo](https://regexr.com/5h0lo).

The pattern does the following:

- Looks for two hashes followed by a version number, right at the start of the string - `^## (\d+\.?){3}`.
- Looks ahead for another two hashes followed by a number (start of the next set of notes) - `(?=## \d)`
- Grabs all the characters in between the two, aiming for as few characters as possible - `.+?`

To make this work, you need the `dotall` flag enabled, so `.` can match newline characters.

Comment: Note your regex [will match](https://regexr.com/5h0oc) across more sections if there are any. [My solution](https://regex101.com/r/IleRL8/3) will still correctly match the first section.

Comment: Good catch, thank you - I've updated mine to be less greedy.

Comment: There are still two things: 1) `## \d`  matches anywhere on a line, not only at the start, which again might be unwelcome, 2) [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/2xaPVg/1) (499) takes a double amount more steps than [mine](https://regex101.com/r/IleRL8/2) (123) due to the [unroll-the-loop principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018490/3832970) used in  my solution.

Comment: Thank you again - you're absolutely right. I can fix the line-start thing easily, but that makes mine even less efficient. I'll read through the unrolling principle link. Thanks once more.