# Matching groups of things, separated by specific token

Tags: regex, ruby

So, here's what I'm trying to do, although I've been struggling with that for some time.

Let's say we have this input:

```
{{something|a}} text text {{another|one|with|more|items}}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
[
    ["something", "a"],
    ["another", "one", "with", "more", "items"]
]
```

---

The simple way would be something like:

```rb
"{{something|a}} text text {{another|one|with|more|items}}".scan(/([^\|\{\}]+)/)
```

But this yields - quite predictably so - all the results in a single array (also note that I *do not want* "text text" in the results, just the items IN the curly braces):

```
[["something"], ["a"], [" text text "], ["another"], ["one"], ["with"], ["more"], ["items"]]
```

I then tried doing it like ([see script here](https://rubular.com/r/Lmzj48cFCzse4w)):

```
\{\{(([^\|\{\}]+)\|?)+\}\}
```

But I must be doing something wrong.

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: You can't get all capture values of some group in Ruby. There are always as many captures as the capturing groups in the pattern. So, `.scan(/{{(.*?)}}/).flatten.map{ |x| x.split("|") }` [seems to work](https://ideone.com/s6iYK0) here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So simple and so straightforward. I should have though of approaching it like that... Thanks a lot! (Just post it as an answer and I will gladly accept it :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get all captured values of a [repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) in Ruby.
There are always as many captures as the capturing groups in the pattern.

Thus, you need to throw in some  more code to get the expected output:

```rb
s = '{{something|a}} text text {{another|one|with|more|items}}'
p s.scan(/{{(.*?)}}/).flatten.map{ |x| x.split("|") }
# => [["something", "a"], ["another", "one", "with", "more", "items"]]
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/s6iYK0).

Note the `{{(.*?)}}` pattern matches a `{{` substring, then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible and then `}}`, then `.flatten` turns the result into a string array, and then `x.split("|")` within a  `map` call splits the found capturing group values with `|`.

NOTE: if there can be line breaks in between `{{` and `}}`, add `/m` modifier, `/{{(.*?)}}/m`. Or, unroll the pattern for better efficiency: `/{{[^}]*(?:}(?!})[^}]*)*}}/` (see [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/5GwK3F6plzOxLy)).

Comment: Thanks again! Great answer :)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Thank *you* for a very good and clear question. If you wonder what I meant by "unroll the pattern", please refer to [Unroll Loop, when to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018490/3832970).