# Apache2 Regular Expression Optional Capture Group

Tags: regex, apache2

Need help with a problem that has been bothering me for some time!

I am attempting to create an Apache `AliasMatch` Regular Expression that will match a URL. The Issue I'm having is that I am using the capture groups as variables `$0 $1 $2` within the file match portion. Essentially I need to capture the `path/to/controller` portion of the url to actually grab my file and I wish to not use any capture groups after and including the double forward slashes.

http://domain.com/etc/xx/abc/**path/to/controller**//myDesiredMVCAction

The issue Essentially is that with the following expression:

`^/etc/(xx|yy)/(abc|xyz)/(.*)(?=//)(.*)`

it only matches

`http://domain.com/etc/xx/abc/path/to/controller//myDesiredMVCAction`

and not:

`http://domain.com/etc/xx/abc/path/to/controller`

given that the double slashes and everything trailing it is optional.

So when I make the regex expression optional by appending a `?` it ruins the capture group by including the `//myDesiredMVCAction` portion..

`^/etc/(xx|yy)/(abc|xyz)/(.*)(?=//)(.*)?`

It is possible to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use

```
^/etc/(xx|yy)/(abc|xyz)/(.*?)(?://.*)?$
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eA8kW4/1)

The thing is, the `(.*?)(?://.*)?$` part of the pattern works in such a way that `(.*?)` is not tried first since it is lazily quantified with `*?`, and `(?://.*)?$` is tried first, and when the latter does not match, the `(.*?)` expands, writing a character to the group value at each expansion step.

The pattern matches:

- `^/etc/` - `/etc/` after base URL
- `(xx|yy)/` - `xx` or `yy` and then a `/`
- `(abc|xyz)/` - an `abc` or `xyz` and a `/` after them
- `(.*?)` - any zero or more characters, *but as few as possible* before the first
- `(?://.*)?`  - (optional group due to `?` at the end) two `/`s followed with any characters, as many as possible up to
- `$` - the end of the string input.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor! Seems like greedy quantification was not analogous to my thought process.. Learnt something new for the day: IQ + 1 ;)

Comment: How lazy and greedy quantifiers work when used together is difficult to understand. I suggest you take a look at [*Can I improve performance of this regular expression further*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869557/can-i-improve-performance-of-this-regular-expression-further/33869801#33869801).