# Regex capture order: wrong alternative matched after greedy pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have this pattern:

```
(\w+)(sin|in|pak|red)$
```

And the replacement *pattern* is this:

```
$1tak
```

The problem is that this word:

> setesin

will be transformed to:

> setestak

instead of

> setetak

For some reason, `in` always takes precedence to `sin` in the pattern.

How can I enforce the pattern to follow that order?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a lazy quantifier:

```
(\w+?)(sin|in|pak|red)$
    ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TQaq1h/1)

The `\w+` contains a greedy quantifier that: 1) grabs as many chars as it can (and note it can match `s`, `i`, all letters, digits and underscores) and then backtracks (yielding one char after another moving from right to left), trying to accommodate for the subsequent patterns. Since the `in` is found first, it is matched, and the whole group is considered matched, the regex goes on to check the end of string with `$`.  A lazy quantifier will have the regex engine skip the `\w+?` after matching 1 word char, and other patterns will be tried, moving from left to right.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Will accept the answer in a few mins

Comment: Greedy quantifiers cause *backtracking*  - that is, the subsequent patterns are found at the rightmost locations. Lazy quantfiers cause the subpattern *expansion* (a reverse backtracking) and the subsequent subpatterns are found at the leftmost locations. It is not appropriate to say lazy or greedy quantifiers define the order of pattern matching, but it looks as if it were so.

Comment: @Cornwell Lazy means it will not stop matching once it's matched the `in` but will continue checking which means it will eventually match `sin`. It will only match `in` if that is an exact match, i.e. there is no `sin` to match

Comment: Also, see [more examples of how lazy and greedy quantifiers work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869557/can-i-improve-performance-of-this-regular-expression-further/33869801#33869801).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a quantifier at all:

```
(\w)(?:sin|in|pak|red)$
```

with the same replacement

or

```
\B(?:sin|in|pak|red)$
```

with `tak` as replacement. The non-word-boundary `\B` ensures that there's a word character before (If a first word character isn't mandatory before the alternation remove the `\B`).

With these two ways the first occurrences on the left are found first and are not consumed by the greedy quantifier.