# extract string betwen two strings in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a text column that looks like:

```
http://start.blabla.com/landing/fb603?&mkw...
```

I want to extract "start.blabla.com"
which is always between:

```
http://
```

and:

```
/landing/
```

namely:

```
start.blabla.com
```

I do:

```
df.col.str.extract('http://*?\/landing')
```

But it doesn't work. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `http://([^/]+)/landing`

Comment: works! can you explain me your solution? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You are missing the capturing parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer a question you didn't ask, if you wanted to extract several portions of the string into separate columns, you'd do it this way:

```
df.col.str.extract('http://(?P<Site>.*?)/landing/(?P<RestUrl>.*)')
```

You'd get something along the lines of:

```
               Site        RestUrl
0  start.blabla.com  fb603?&mkw...
```

To understand how this regex (and any other regex for that matter) is constructed I suggest you take a look at the excellent site regex101. I constructed a snippet where you can see the above regex in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/CIvj64/3).

Answer (score 9):

Your regex matches `http:/`, then 0+ `/` symbols as few as possible and then `/landing`.

You need to match and *capture* the characters ([*The `extract` method accepts a regular expression with at least one capture group.*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings)) after `http://` other than `/`, 1 or more times. It can be done with

```
http://([^/]+)/landing
       ^^^^^^^
```

where `[^/]+` is a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches 1+ occurrences of characters other than `/`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9yVWIg/1)

Comment: Why not `http:\/\/(.*?)\/landing` ?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi: Because `.*?` causes unnecessary "forward backtracking" (lazy pattern "expansion"), thus requiring more "steps" for the regex engine to return a match compared to a negated character class that just grabs 1+ chars other than `/` (here) and then checks `/landing`. With `.*?` the `/landing` substring is searched for already after matching `http://` - and we know it is not right there. This check repeats after each char in the host value. People often say regex is "overkill" for cases where a simple string method should do. It is the same situation: if `[^/]` will do, use it.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: If you mean to ask for more details/examples of how lazy patterns work, see [*Can I improve performance of this regular expression further*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33869801/3832970).

Comment: This won't notify the OP. Maybe if you comment below question, it would.

Comment: @MYGz When you try adding 2 user tags in a comment, the popup says: *Only one additional `@user` can be notified; the post owner will always be notified*. Any comment here should notify OP.

Comment: You have 0 questions or I would have tested it :P

Comment: Did you get a notification for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340341/pythonic-way-for-calculating-length-of-lists-in-pandas-dataframe-column?

Comment: Ok, I added the comment under the question.