# Sort dataframe by string length

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, series, reindex

I want to sort by name length. There doesn't appear to be a `key` parameter for `sort_values` so I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Here is a test df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Steve', 'Al', 'Markus', 'Greg'], 'score': [2, 4, 2, 3]})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort dataframe by length of string in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177362/sort-dataframe-by-length-of-string-in-a-column)

Comment: @jezrael Please read my reason. I mentioned it explicitly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177362/sort-dataframe-by-length-of-string-in-a-column#comment79318016_46177362

Comment: There are more options there. If not, you can edit this answer and include all those other solutions.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) of `index` of `Series` created by [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
print (df.name.str.len())
0    5
1    2
2    6
3    4
Name: name, dtype: int64

print (df.name.str.len().sort_values())
1    2
3    4
0    5
2    6
Name: name, dtype: int64

s = df.name.str.len().sort_values().index
print (s)
Int64Index([1, 3, 0, 2], dtype='int64')

print (df.reindex(s))
     name  score
1      Al      4
3    Greg      3
0   Steve      2
2  Markus      2
```

---

```
df1 = df.reindex(s)
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
     name  score
0      Al      4
1    Greg      3
2   Steve      2
3  Markus      2
```

Comment: Great answer, I tried this approach with lists too (Sorting a DataFrame by list length), since `.str.len()` works with lists as mentioned in the question **Pythonic way for calculating length of lists in pandas dataframe column** in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340341/pythonic-way-for-calculating-length-of-lists-in-pandas-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 47):

Using [**`DataFrame.sort_values`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) we can pass an anonymous (lambda) function computing string length (using `.str.len()` Series method) to the **`key`** argument:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Steve', 'Al', 'Markus', 'Greg'], 
    'score': [2, 4, 2, 3]
})
print(df)

     name  score
0   Steve      2
1      Al      4
2  Markus      2
3    Greg      3
```

```
df.sort_values(by="name", key=lambda x: x.str.len())

     name  score
1      Al      4
3    Greg      3
0   Steve      2
2  Markus      2
```

Comment: Thanks. Just in case someone needs to lower case and sort `df.sort_index(key=lambda x: x.str.lower().str.len())`

Answer (score 16):

I found this solution more intuitive, specially if you want to do something depending on the column length later on.

```py
df['length'] = df['name'].str.len()
df.sort_values('length', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Now your dataframe will have a column with name `length` with the value of string length from column `name` in it and the whole dataframe will be sorted in descending order.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much simpler and easily reused.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @jezrael is great and explains well. Here is the final result :

```
index_sorted = df.name.str.len().sort_values(ascending=True).index
df_sorted = df.reindex(index_sorted)
df_sorted = df_sorted.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

A fancy and minimal solution:

```
df.iloc[df.agg({"name":len}).sort_values('name').index]



     name  score
1      Al      4
3    Greg      3
0   Steve      2
2  Markus      2
```

Comment: Nice one! thanxx !!

Answer (score 0):

It's worth using the `key` argument to avoid creating unnecessary columns:

```py
df.sort_values("column_name", ascending=True, key=lambda col: col.str.len())
```