# Sort dataframe by length of a string column

Tags: python, string, pandas, sorting, dataframe

Using Python. I have a dataframe with three columns:

```
Author | Title | Reviews
```

I want to sort by the length of the string in the Reviews column.

If I do

```
df.sort_values('Review', ascending = False)
```

It sorts alphabetically, starting with '`z`'.

How do I get it to sort by the length of the string in the Reviews column?

Answer (score 6):

I think you need [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for lengths assign to index, [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Author':list('abcdef'),
                   'Title ':list('abcdef'),
                   'Review':['aa', 'aasdd', 'dwd','dswee dass', 'a', 'sds']})

print (df)
  Author      Review Title 
0      a          aa      a
1      b       aasdd      b
2      c         dwd      c
3      d  dswee dass      d
4      e           a      e
5      f         sds      f

df.index = df['Review'].str.len()
df = df.sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  Author      Review Title 
0      d  dswee dass      d
1      b       aasdd      b
2      c         dwd      c
3      f         sds      f
4      a          aa      a
5      e           a      e
```

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**
Using *`df.argsort`* and *`df.reindex`*

```
df

   Review
0     abc
1  foo123
2       b

df = df.reindex((-df.Review.str.len()).argsort()).reset_index(drop=True)
df

  Review
0  foo123
1     abc
2       b
```

---

**Option 2**
Similar solution using *`np.argsort`*

```
df = df.reindex(np.argsort(-df.Review.str.len())).reset_index(drop=True)
df

   Review
0  foo123
1     abc
2       b
```

---

**Option 3**
Using *`df.sort_values`* and *`df.iloc`*

```
df = df.iloc[(-df.Review.str.len()).argsort()].reset_index(drop=True)
df

   Review
0  foo123
1     abc
2       b
```