# Why is 'key' an unexpected keyword of sort_values()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, typeerror

I am trying to implement the code

```
sort_order = {
'Documentary':0,
'Film-Noir':1,
'Biography':2,
'History':3,
'War':4,
'News':5,
'Animation':6,
'Musical':7,
'Music':8,
'Drama':9
}

df.sort_values(by=['genre'], key=lambda x: x.map(sort_order))
```

But I receive this error:

```
TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'
```

I downloaded the latest version of Pandas to try and fix this using conda update pandas but this did not change anything. I know something is going wrong because their page [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) shows that key should be recognized.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your version of Pandas might not be recent. I'd suggest you update to the latest version

Comment: I have already tried that. I used this 'conda update pandas' to update it. For some reason, it still doesn't work though.

Comment: what is your pandas version number?

Comment: I think last time I checked it was 1.0.5

Comment: You need to upgrade to 1.1

Comment: Thanks, I searched how to get that specific version and it now works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, [Sorting with Keys is introduced in version 1.1.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#sorting-with-keys).

You may run the following to update the package (note the `-U` flag):

```
python -m pip install -U pandas
```

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516653/812102) may be inspiring for people who don’t have access to this version.