# Python Pandas compare two dataframes with a similar (string) column, where 1 df's values are substrings of the other df's values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, startswith

I have a large CSV with phone number prefixes, and corresponding country names.
Then I have a smaller dataframe with prefixes, and corresponding country names that are spelled wrong. I need to find a way to replace the smaller df's country names with the ones from the CSV. Unfortunately, I can't simply compare `csv_df['prefix'] == small_df['prefix']`.

The smaller dataframe contains very long, specific prefixes ("3167777"), while the CSV has less specific prefixes ("31"). As you can imagine, a prefix like 3167777 is a subcategory of 31, and therefore belongs to the CSV's 31-group. However, if the CSV contains a more specific prefix ("316"), then the longer prefix should only belong to that group.

Dummy example data:

```
# CSV-df with correct country names
prefix      country
93,         Portugal
937,        Portugal Special Numbers
31,         Netherlands
316,        Netherlands Special Numbers

# Smaller df with wrong country names
prefix      country
93123,      PT
9377777,    PT
3121,       NL
31612345,   NL
31677777,   NL
31688888,   NL
```

Ideal result:

```
# Smaller df, but with correct country names
prefix      country
9312345,    Portugal
9377777,    Portugal Special Numbers
3121,       Netherlands
31612345,   Netherlands Special Numbers
31677777,   Netherlands Special Numbers
31688888,   Netherlands Special Numbers
```

So far, I have a very slow, non-elegant solution: I've put the smaller df's prefixes in a list, and loop through the list, constantly .

```
# small_df_prefixes = ['9312345', '3167', '31612345', ...]
for prefix in small_df_prefixes:
    # See if the prefix occurs in the CSV
    if prefix in [p[:len(prefix)] for p in csv_df['prefix']]:
        new_dest = csv_df.loc[csv_df['prefix'] == prefix]['destination'].values[0]
    else:
        new_dest = 'UNKNOWN'
```

This runs slowly and does not give me the solution I need. I've looked into panda's `startswith` and `contains` functions but can't quite figure out how to use them correctly here. I hope someone can help me out with a better solution.

Comment: Is is guaranteed that the prefixed are unique? Moreover, if they are unique, why would you have `Portugal` two times, both starting with `93`? Wouldn't it be easier if you had a key mapping like `{'PT': 'Portugal', 'NL': 'Netherlands'}`?

Comment: Ah I made the dummy data a bit too dummy. Basically, there's some large prefix-categories in the CSV, every category is basically a phone provider in the country. There are so many providers that mapping them manually would be impossible...


A prefix never occurs more than once in a df.  However, the more provider-specific, long prefixes (316777) do have overlap with the basic country prefixes (316).

Comment: But do you need to map `93` to `Portugal` and `937` to `Portugal Special Numbers`?

Comment: Yes I do. So if I have new phone number, for example: 93777, it would be long to Portugal Special Numbers. But 93111 would belong to Portugal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should take a look into [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). It enable you to apply a function either column or row wise on a `DataFrame`.

The idea here is to order `df_right` (which has the right names) by the lenght of the prefix (the longer the more specific) and then tries to exactly match the prefix in `df_wrong` to a prefix in `df_right`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df_wrong = pd.read_csv('path/to/wrong.csv')
# df_wrong
# prefix      country
# 9312345     PT
# 3167        NL
# ...         ...

df_right = pd.read_csv('path/to/right.csv')
# df_right
# prefix      country
# 93          Portugal
# 937         Portugal Special Numbers
# 31          Netherlands
# ...         ...

# because prefixes 93 != 937, we will sort values by their len, as 93 would contain 937
df_right.sort_values(by = 'prefix', key = lambda prefix: prefix.len(), inplace = True, ascending = False)

def correct_country(prefix):
    global df_right
    equal_match = df_right[df_right.prefix == prefix].country
    if equal_math.shape[0] == 0: # no matches
         return 'UNKNOWN'
    return equal_match[0]

df_wrong['corrected_country'] = df_wrong['prefix'].apply(correct_prefix)
```

Resources:

- [Sort Dataframe by String Lenght](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516616/sort-dataframe-by-string-length)

Comment: I've tried running this but I'm getting some errors... Especially on the line: `df_right.sort_values(...`  the lambda function is giving me a keyerror: 'prefix'

Comment: Ok after some tweaking i got it to work... However, the correct_country() function only looks at exact matches (example: 3167777 == 317777). However, I need it to look at the first n digits of the prefix: if 3167777 doesnt exist but 316 does, then I need 316777 to get 316's country label.

Comment: The line `equal_match = df_right[df_right.prefix == prefix].country`  is the only one that needs changing. Instead of `==`, I need something that says "the longest prefix in df_right that matches the first digits of the current prefix".    // Ive thought of using 'startswith', but I don't know how to apply it to get the result I want (the country).

Comment: I'm sorry about the `prefix` thing: I was not sure if pandas would pass the entire DataFrame or just the column. I believe that, instead of using the boolean part (inside the brackets), use `df_right.prefix.apply(lambda p: p.startswith(prefix))` which will return a boolean series where that column starts with the prefix you want. Then, you just need to get the lowest match (index `-1`) or get the first one if `ascending = True`. Hope this helps! Good coding!