# Python: Efficient way to get the length of lists for a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting the following series. I want to calculate the length of list for each country.

```
Scotland                [1074957, 1074964, 1074968, 1074970, 287855, 3...
South Africa            [1020029, 1031431, 1031433, 1031435, 222678, 2...
Sri Lanka               [1001349, 1001351, 1001353, 1083449, 1083450, ...
United Arab Emirates    [1072206, 1072207, 1072208, 1074962, 1074965, ...
West Indies             [1041615, 1041617, 1050217, 1050219, 1050221, ...
Zimbabwe                [1007655, 1007657, 1007659, 287856, 287858, 41...
Name: Id, dtype: object
```

such that the resulting series OR Dataframe will be

```
Scotland              35
South Africa          57
Sri Lanka             12
United Arab Emirates  31
West Indies           74
Zimbabwe               9
```

In Pandas how can we do this in a Pythonic way?

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: len(x))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340341/pythonic-way-for-calculating-length-of-lists-in-pandas-dataframe-column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.len()` only:

```
a.str.len()
```

And for columns of `DataFrame`:

```
df['col'].str.len()
```

But if no `NaN`s values `apply(len)` working more efficient:

```
a.apply(len)

df['col'].apply(len)
```

List comprehension solutions:

```
pd.Series([len(x) for x in a], index=a.index)
pd.Series([len(x) for x in df['col']], index=df.index)
```

Comment: Glad I found this, this is really  un-intuitive - especially if you've just applied `literal_eval` to the lists in your series stored in a file to import to the dataframe. the last place you'd look for list methods is in `str` methods