# Calculating Length of List of List in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem that is extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721324/python-efficient-way-to-get-the-length-of-lists-for-a-pandas-series) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340341/pythonic-way-for-calculating-length-of-lists-in-pandas-dataframe-column). Suppose I have dataframe like this:

```
    A   B
0   1   [["Thing_1"]]
1   2   [["Thing_1"], ["Thing_2"]]
2   3   [["Thing_1", "Thing_2"], ["Thing_2"]]
3   4   [["Thing_1"], ["Thing_1", "Thing_2"]]
4   5   [["Thing_1", "Thing_2"], ["Thing_1", "Thing_2"]]
```

Instead of getting like this:

```
    A   B                                                 C(result of length in column B)
0   1   [["Thing_1"]]                                     1
1   2   [["Thing_1"], ["Thing_2"]]                        2
2   3   [["Thing_1", "Thing_2"], ["Thing_2"]]             2
3   4   [["Thing_1"], ["Thing_1", "Thing_2"]]             2
4   5   [["Thing_1", "Thing_2"], ["Thing_1", "Thing_2"]]  2
```

the column C becomes the length of the characters in the lists of lists rather than the outer length of lists of lists using these functions: `df['B'].str.len()` and `df['B'].apply(len)`. How can I get the result right?

Comment: `df.B.str.len()`  seems to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe your column B is actually of type string, since it's giving you a length of the characters, so try first with `ast.literal_eval` to change the column from string type to lists, and then use `df['B'].apply(len)` or `df['B'].str.len()`

```
import ast
df['B']=df['B'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df['C']=df['B'].apply(len)
```

---

Or if you only need the length without changing the type of  column B, try with a single `apply`

```
df['C']=df['B'].apply(lambda x:ast.literal_eval(x)).str.len()
```

---

Output:

```
df
   A                                                 B  C
0  1                                     [["Thing_1"]]  1
1  2                        [["Thing_1"], ["Thing_2"]]  2
2  3             [["Thing_1", "Thing_2"], ["Thing_2"]]  2
3  4             [["Thing_1"], ["Thing_1", "Thing_2"]]  2
4  5  [["Thing_1", "Thing_2"], ["Thing_1", "Thing_2"]]  2
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I had figured that about three minutes before you answered, but nevertheless, since you pointed out my problem, you'd have my vote.

Comment: You´re welcome, no worries, glad you found a solution to your problem! Happy coding!:)