# when grouping dataframe join the values that are different for a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm first going to show with an example what I mean:

Let's suppose that I have this dataframe:

[image]

If I group the dataframe **without** the penultimate column (column_2), I want to end up with this:

[image]

And, if I have a dataframe where column_1 and last_column have the same values. I don't need to "join" or "append" the values in the "column_2", I just want an empty dataframe.

Does that make sense what I mean? What I've just have is this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'column_1': ['no', 'no', 'no', 'no'], 'column_2': ['spain', 'france', 'italy', 'germany'], "last_column": ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

aux = df.drop(columns = ['column_2'])
indices_to_keep = aux.groupby(aux.columns.to_list()).filter(lambda x : len(x)<2).index
df_to_keep = df.filter(items = indices_to_keep.to_list(), axis = 0)
```

My problem with this code, is that I don't know how to join the values on a single row when the df is being grouped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just [aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) into a `list`:

```py
df.groupby(
    ['column_1', 'last_column']
)['column_2'].agg(list).reset_index()[
    ['column_1', 'column_2', 'last_column']
]
```

Comment: oh didn't know it was possible! awesome! any idea of how to preserve the order of the columns? @Matt I'm trying by adding "sort = False" but is still showing the same

Comment: Thanks @Matt. Is there any way to filter the rows when the length of the result of the aggregation is 1? I mean, for this case, suppose "last_column" = A. Then I don't want aggregation since everything is the same.

Comment: if you let this answer be ‘new_df’ then you can just filter down to those rows where the list column has length greater than 1: new_df[new_df[‘column_2’].apply(len) > 1] ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340341/how-to-determine-the-length-of-lists-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column))