# non-greedy matches greedy?

Tags: regex

There is probably a really simple explanation but I just don't see it right now...
I have this regex:

```
(\s.+?\sstress)
```

I want it to match something like `[SPACE]some word[SPACE]stress`. However it matches to much:

```
This will cause a lot of work stress
```

will match:  `will cause a lot of work stress` 
 But `.+?` should be non-greedy so I expected it to only match `work stress`.
Click [here](https://regex101.com/r/WFNZJf/1) to open this in regex101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*?` is non-greedy, but the regex engine works from left to right, and the first `\s` matches the left-most whitespace, and `.` can match any char, and thus, although it is lazily quantified, it must get to the whitespace followed with `stress` substring.

To just get `work stress`, use

```
\s(\S+\sstress)
```

or just

```
\S+\s+stress
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rPPHR1/1).

The main point here it to exclude whitespace matching between the first `\s` and the second `\s` in the regex. `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace symbols and is a more restrictive pattern compared to `.`.

Comment: Is this left-to-right approach always the case? In other words is this the case in every programming lanuage?

Comment: Can you please explain the second regex?

Comment: In .NET and PyPi regex, you may tell the regex engine to parse the string from right to left using a special regex option. See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs.%2b%3f%5csstress&i=This+will+cause+a+lot+of+work+stress&o=r&s=36). I updated the answer with a short description of the main change - using `\S` shorthand character class. It matches the same as `[^\s]` - any char but whitespace.

Comment: @CodeNoob: Is it fine now, or should I add more details?

Comment: Oow I see, never knew that \S existed hahah thankyou!

Comment: @CodeNoob: These are called reverse/opposite character classes: `\d` ~ `\D`, `\s` ~ `\S`, `\w` ~ `\W`, `\p{UNICODE_CATEGRY}` ~ `\P{UNICODE_CATEGRY}`. Even `\b` (word boundary) and `\B` (any position other than a word boundary) also follow the same "behavior".

Comment: thankyou for the thorough explanation! Learned something today :)

Comment: @CodeNoob: Also, please read [this answer of mine to learn how lazy quantifiers work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869557/can-i-improve-performance-of-this-regular-expression-further/33869801#33869801) (the *Difference between `.*?`, `.*` and `[^"]*+` quantifiers* section).