# How to insert a character every n characters from end of string

Tags: r, regex

I would like to insert a colon every five characters starting from the end of the string, preferably using regex and gsub in R.

```
text <- "My Very Enthusiastic Mother Just Served Us Noodles!"
```

I have been able to insert a colon every five characters from beginning of the text using:

```
gsub('(.{5})', "\\1:", text, perl = T)
```

I have written an inelegant function for achieving this as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
str_reverse<-function(x){
  strsplit(x,split='')[[1]] %>% rev() %>% paste(collapse = "") 
}

text2<-str_reverse(text)
text3<-gsub('(.{5})', "\\1:", text2, perl = T)
str_reverse(text3)
```

to get the desired result

> [1] "M:y Ver:y Ent:husia:stic :Mothe:r Jus:t Ser:ved U:s Noo:dles!"

Is there a way this can be achieved directly using regular expressions?

Comment: Consider that the `stringi` package has the `stri_reverse` function already available and super efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
gsub('(?=(?:.{5})+$)', ":", text, perl = TRUE)
## => [1] "M:y Ver:y Ent:husia:stic :Mothe:r Jus:t Ser:ved U:s Noo:dles!"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/liENfO/1)

The `(?=(?:.{5})+$)` pattern matches any location inside the string that is followed with any 5 chars (other than line break chars) 1 or more times up to the end of the string.

If the input string can contain line breaks you need to add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern (since `.` in PCRE regex does not match line breaks by default):

```
'(?s)(?=(?:.{5})+$)'
```

Comment: @AndreElrico 1) It does not matter if you use lazy or greedy quantifiers here, `(?=(?:.{5})+?$)` = `(?=(?:.{5})+$)` because the next pattern is `$`, end of string and `.{5}` goes matching up to the end of the string anyway, 2) since the regex searches for matches from left to right, the 2nd position is matched, not the 5 from the end. PCRE regex cannot be set to search from the end.

Comment: thanks you also found this here https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#longest_shortest . this was a  missing piece in my brain

Comment: @AndreElrico You may want to read [my quantfier explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33869801/3832970), too.