# Remove only the begining of previous email

Tags: python, regex

I'm wondering how to remove any header of previous message in an email. There is an example of message:

```
Something above

-----Message d'origine-----
De : Myself <myself@himself.com>
Envoyé : vendredi 8 mars 2019 14:30
À : Someone <someone@himself.com>
Cc : AnotherGuy <another@himself.com>
Objet : My bad I forgot how to do it

Hi,

blabla
```

And I need to remove everything between `-----Message d'origine-----` and the `carriage return` and the `empty new line` before `"Hi,"`.

I've tried the following regex:

```
-----Message d'origine-----[\s\S]*?[\r\n]
```

But only `-----Message d'origine-----` matched without the other lines below. However, if I use instead `"Hi,"`, it matches all lines with it:

```
-----Message d'origine-----[\s\S]*?Hi
```

Is anyone can help me where is the problem and how to use instead the `carriage return` and the `empty new line` ?

Thank you :)

Comment: You’ve shown the regex you tried but not the corresponding Python code. This matters: Did you enable multiline regex matching?

Comment: Easy. Match two newlines instead of one: `(?:\r?\n){2}`. This is a duplicate.

Comment: @revo Duplicate of *what?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to match until the first occurrence of *double* linebreak:

```
r"-----Message d'origine-----[\s\S]*?(?:\r?\n){2}"
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RFsFXs/2). The `(?:\r?\n){2}` pattern matches two repetitions of a CRLF or LF line endings.

Sample Python code:

```
import re
s = "YOUR STRING HERE"
s = re.sub(r"-----Message d'origine-----.*?(?:\r?\n){2}", '', s, flags=re.S)
```

Note that `[\s\S]` is equal to `.` in a regex when the `re.S` (=`re.DOTALL` flag is used).

If you are concerned with performance that is impacted by the non-greedy `.*?` pattern, unroll it as

```
s = re.sub(r"-----Message d'origine-----.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*\s*", "", s)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RFsFXs/3). Do not use `re.S` / `re.DOTALL` with this pattern!

The `[\s\S]*?(?:\r?\n){2}` is now `.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*`:

- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `\r?\n(?!\r?\n)` - a linebreak not followed with another line break
  - `.*` - the rest of the line

Comment: Why would the non-greedy pattern be less efficient than your alternative? I don’t know the internals of Python’s regex engine but naively they should be performing pretty much the same kind of work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Check the number of steps for both regexps at regex101: 582 / 72. The difference is due to backtracking with `.*?` pattern since the pattern is expanded each time the subsequent patterns fail to match. `.*` grabs all chars up to the line break and there is less backtracking here since a check is made after the end of line is found, no need to expand any pattern char by char.

Comment: Hmm this strikes me as a performance bug in the implementation: surely the nongreedy match could be implemented in the same way?

Comment: @KonradRudolph That is expected behavior and no bug. See [Can I improve performance of this regular expression further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869557) for a concrete example of how `.*` and `.*?` match. When dealing with long texts it is a bad idea to rely on `.*?` or `.*` if you are not sure about match positions. [Unroll the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018490/3832970) method should be used then, or discard regex altogether in favor  of some parsing method.

Comment: Right, I got confused. I misunderstood you as saying that the `.*?` *itself* backtracks, rather than the following `(?:\r?\n){2}` (which is matched at each steps and usually fails). I had also missed that your second example isn’t running in single-line mode, so `.` simply matches *less*, and *that’s* why it’s more efficient than the non-greedy case.

Comment: Great @WiktorStribiżew thanks for all the tips you provided :) I was pretty near but I did not know the concept of flags here, and how to improve performance here