# How to speed up regex findall in a CSS file

Tags: python, css, regex

I'm using regex to find all selectors in CSS files and sometimes, it loads for minutes. After looking at the files, I found out that the sourceMappingURL is really large and cause the issue:

```
sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIndvb2QuZnVsbC5taW4uY3NzIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJpQkFFQSw4QkFBOEIsU0FBUyxPQUFPLGlCQUFpQixPQUFPLEtBQUssb0JBQW9CLEtBQUssUUFBUSxPQUFPLEVBQUUsU0FBUyxtQkFBbUIsSUFBSSxRQUFRLFdBQVcsT0FBTyxvQkFBb0IsNEJBQTRCLE9BTyxL...
```

Here's the full CSS file: https://jsfiddle.net/jj_jaq/32d7hpc0/3/

Here's my regex:

```
selectors = re.findall(r'([.#\w][-\w,\s.]+)(\{(.*?)\})', content)
```

Is there a way to speed up my regex?

Comment: Try it changing `.*?` to `[^{}]*`

Comment: See [Can I improve performance of this regular expression further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869557/can-i-improve-performance-of-this-regular-expression-further/33869801)

Comment: @Thefourthbird tried it, still takes for ages

Comment: Please post the real string you have trouble with. A link to pastebin.com will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just added it in the post

Comment: I think I have found a hack, try `[.#]?\b([-\w,\s.]+){([^{}]*)}`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Knm2VE/2). Still a bit slow, but seems working.

Comment: waow, it seems to work ! Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Do you know what exactly was slowing the process down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may tell the regex engine to anchor the matches at left-hand word boundaries. However, just adding `\b` won't work as the first char you want to match can also be a `.` or `#` that are non-word chars.

Use

```
[.#]?\b([-\w,\s.]+){([^{}]*)}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Knm2VE/2) where `[.#]?` matches an optional `.` or `#` before the word boundary check.